# Why doesn't this bluetooth tethering show more than 3mbps Link speed?

Tags: wireless-networking, android, bluetooth, internet-speed, tethering

Bluetooth module as shown by the device manager (which i think corresponds to bluetooth 4?):

`HCI Version 6.258. LMP Version 6.1.` (Qualcomm Atheros AR9485WB-EG)

My phone specs also show Bluetooth 4.1 (details fetched from GSMArena):

`Bluetooth  4.1, A2DP, EDR, LE`

Isn't bluetooth 4+ supposed to have 24mbit speed rather than 3mbit? So why is my bluetooth pan link speed stuck at 3mbit? It's almost as if it's running bluetooth 2+ but the LMP version tells a different story!

I'll also confirm that my phone is using LTE, not Wifi as the internet source.

---

Just in case you wanted to confirm the specs yourself (or point out to something I missed):

```
Laptop: ASUS X551CA
Phone: SAMSUNG A710FD
```

Comment: If you can provide the wireless adapter model for the laptop, that would be a step towards confirming BT HS support on it. But it's quite likely that support is lacking on the phone side anyway.

Comment: Also, notably, your phone lists EDR (2.0 optional) and LE (4.0 optional) but *not* HS (3.0 optional). This doesn't necessarily mean HS isn't supported, but it is rather suspicious.

Comment: It just shows `Qualcomm Atheros Communications` in Manufacturer, the device is listed as `Bluetooth Module` in the device manager. I'm not sure what to look for in the properties/details section.

Comment: Look at your wireless network adapter model - it's almost certainly the same chip.

Comment: Wifi module Qualcomm Atheros AR9485WB-EG, I updated the question as well.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's a *huge* pain to find datasheets (or drivers) for Qualcomm hardware. I've tracked down the WLAN brochure but not the BT one... though [this](https://www.qualcomm.com/news/releases/2011/08/30/qualcomm-atheros-collaborates-acer-bring-latest-bluetooth-technology) might be it, which does do HS.

Comment: I tried connecting to my roommate's laptop too which is running Broadcom BCM43142 bluetooth 4 adapter as well. Linkspeed was still 3mbps. So if Qualcomm supported HS, then I guess the bottleneck is my phone?

Comment: Yup, the [BCM43142](https://www.broadcom.com/products/wireless/wireless-lan-bluetooth/bcm43142) definitely lists HS. Most likely your phone does not support it.

Comment: Additional question, me keeping WiFi 'off' on laptop and phone has nothing to do with bluetooth not using HS, right?

Comment: That's... a good question. You can try enabling them to double-check - I'm seeing conflicting information (some people say it does matter?). Unfortunately it's not something that's easy for me to test at the moment.

Comment: Tried turning it on at both laptops and the phone then reconnecting.  Both laptops remained at 3mbps. No luck there, sadly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The higher speed is only available over 802.11 (effectively, Wi-Fi). You're better off just hosting a Wi-Fi hotspot on the phone.

The key is that [the high-speed part of the spec is entirely optional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth#Bluetooth_3.0_+_HS), and [might not be supported by Android at all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15382241/how-to-enable-high-speed-bluetooth-3-0hs-or-4-0-in-android) (at least as of 2013). It's looking like Android 2.3.x on some specific Samsung firmware might have supported it, but it's not part of Android stock and Samsung dropped it in 4.x. Use Wi-Fi hotspot - it's easier and more reliable.

See also:

- https://www.gsmarena.com/wireless_n_bluetooth_3_speed_test-review-551p4.php
- "Bluetooth High Speed is not supported on ICS." -- https://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=30522137&postcount=14
- "Google hasn't released the API's necessary for the HS functionality." -- https://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=58770481&postcount=8

Comment: The main reason I wanted to stick with Bluetooth was power efficiency, since tethering will be on for a prolonged amount of time (I'm travelling). It does look like the HS feature is very very compatibility dependent.

Comment: @RiA It's possible that the lack of HS support is for the same reason of power efficiency. Keep in mind that HS uses the same physical hardware as Wi-Fi (literally, it uses the same 802.11 PHY) so it's unlikely to be any more efficient. If anything, it'll probably be less efficient.

Comment: Oh! @same hardware, that explains a lot of things! So I guess WiFi direct is also the same thing as transfers over HS bluetooth? Anyway I'll mark this as answer since this clarifies things.

Comment: @RiA Wi-Fi Direct also uses the same 802.11 PHY, yes, but it's a bit different: higher max-speed, does not require BT support.